# SSRS-error about report server database version after hotfixing SQL. The found version is '164'. The expected version is '163'

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs, ssrs-2012

After applying hotfix [KB3194725](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3194725) to our SQL server, the SSRS server throws the following exception when trying to generate a report:

> Exception type: InvalidReportServerDatabaseException
>
> Exception
>   message: The version of the report server database is either in a
>   format that is not valid, or it cannot be read. The found version is
>   '164'. The expected version is '163'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by applying the same hotfix to the SSRS-server.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the version that you got which is *163*, try to apply this query on the

instance hosting your reporter server database.

In my below example, the database is named **ReportServer** :

USE [ReportServer]

DELETE 
 FROM ServerUpgradeHistory WHERE ServerVersion > 163

Comment: I tried this, and the error has changed and now shows as "ReportServerException: Specified cast is not valid."  Any recommendations?